# How can I pass data to a detailpage from a news api in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm fetching json data from a news api in vanilla JS. I created teasers for the fetched informations. When I click on one of the teasers I need to pass a ID and based on the ID some content to another "detail page".
The receiving data looks like this:

```
[{"id":6657824,"title":"Britische Medienaufsicht: 16 Prozent der britischen Kleinkinder schon auf Tiktok","synopsis":"Eine Studie der britischen Medienaufsichtsbehörde Ofcom zeigt, dass 16 Prozent der 4- bis 5-Jährigen bereits Videos der Kurzvideoplattform Tiktok ansehen.","meta":{"pubDate":"2022-03-30T17:36:00+02:00"},"image":{"src":"https://heise.cloudimg.io/v7/_www-heise-de_/imgs/18/3/4/4/4/7/9/9/shutterstock_576828061.jpg-4a293722ddae462b.jpeg?org_if_sml=1&q=70&width=3800","width":"3800","height":"2135","alt":"Kind schaut im Dunkeln auf ein beleuchtetes Display"}}]
```

The JS-Code that generates my teaser + read more button looks like this:

```
        const detail = document.createElement('a');
        const linkText = document.createTextNode("Mehr erfahren");
        detail.appendChild(linkText);
        detail.href = loadNews();
        detail.target="_blank";
        newNews.appendChild(detail)
```

Comment: can you pas it as query params?  link/to/detail-page.hml?id=6657824&foo=bar
if you have too much content which you don't want to encode to query param, you could store your json in the local storage / indexedDB and only pass the id via query param and read the rest from local storage on the detail page?

Comment: You can repost this as the answer, worked like a charm. I made sure to only pass the related informations within the url and not the entire array of responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the relevant information as **query params** e.g. `href = "link/to/detail-page.html?id=6657824"`. and read it on the next page via `new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("id")`.

Also possible to store the whole teasers response in `indexedDB`/ `localStorage` if you want to retrieve it on the next page without fetching them again (e.g. when the server can't send the correct cache headers.)

Comment: Will this product detail page be indexable by Googlebots?